# How to parse a tricky HTML file, using HTML::TreeBuilder

Tags: perl, html-parsing

Suppose, we have the following HTML file:

#### test.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>weight:</b> 120kg<br>
    <b>length:</b> 10cm<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the following data from it?

```
{
'weight' => '120kg',
'length' => '10cm',
}
```

#### parser.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$root->parse_file('test.htm');

#what to do here?

$root->delete( );
```

Comment: @MiguelPrz What benefits will it give?

Comment: Imho, this is an `scraping task`, and you should use tool for easy scraping: like: [Web::Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper) or [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM). The HTML::TreeBuilder is too low level.

Comment: @jm666 I never used them before. Will try, thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This gets you very close to what you want (you'll need to tweak the text strings you're getting for the keys and values slightly).

But I think you'll find it far simpler using a tool like [Web:Scraper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dumper;
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $root = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
$root->parse_file(\*DATA);

my $data;

foreach my $elem ($root->find('b')) {
  $data->{($elem->content_list)[0]} = $elem->right;
}

say Dumper $data;

__END__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>weight:</b> 120kg<br>
    <b>length:</b> 10cm<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'length:' => ' 10cm',
          'weight:' => ' 120kg'
        };
```

Comment: But it's the **wrong approach**. I can't emphasis that strongly enough.

Comment: As I said before, a tool like Web::Scraper.

Comment: @DaveCross I don't know `Web::Scraper` yet.  Would you perhaps be willing to add a new solution that uses that?  I almost feel that this example data is too simple.  Had trouble coming up with a `Mojo::DOM` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions using [`Mojo::DOM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::DOM;
use Data::Dump;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new(do {local $/; <DATA>});

my %hash = do {
    my $text = $dom->find('body')->all_text();
    split ' ', $text;
};

dd \%hash;

my %hash2 = map {
    $_->all_text() => $_->next_sibling() =~ s{^\s+|\s+$}{}gr
} $dom->find('b')->each;

dd \%hash2;

__DATA__
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <b>weight:</b> 120kg<br>
    <b>length:</b> 10cm<br>
  </body>
</html>
```

Outputs:

```
{ "length:" => "10cm", "weight:" => "120kg" }
{ "length:" => "10cm", "weight:" => "120kg" }
```